# Suppress 'SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed' errors in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, suppress-warnings, urllib3, pyvmomi

I am having trouble using pyVmomi with python 2.7.5. I get SSL certificate errors when trying to run the sample scripts from the SDK. I tried all the solutions mentioned on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981545/suppress-insecurerequestwarning-unverified-https-request-is-being-made-in-pytho/) post but none of them worked for me.

Below is the complete console output.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning. SNIMissingWarning /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning. InsecurePlatformWarning

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello_world_vcenter.py", line 105, in <module>
    main()
  File "hello_world_vcenter.py", line 80, in main
    port=int(args.port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyVim/connect.py", line 663, in SmartConnect
    sslContext)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyVim/connect.py", line 552, in __FindSupportedVersion
    sslContext)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyVim/connect.py", line 472, in __GetServiceVersionDescription
    tree = __GetElementTreeFromUrl(url, sslContext)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyVim/connect.py", line 440, in __GetElementTreeFromUrl
    sock = requests.get(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 67, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 447, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Comment: Try using python 2.7.9 or 2.7.10.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like you're using a self-signed certificate. While connecting via `SmartConnect` use your own sslContext and disable certificate verification.

```
from pyVim.connect import SmartConnect
import ssl

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

si = SmartConnect(host=somehost.com, port=443, user=someone, pwd=secret, sslContext=context)
```

... or use a signed ssl certificate.

There are a few similiar questions on here (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31454255/pyvmomi-smartconnect-throw-error-requests-exceptions-sslerror-errno-8-ssl-c)).